'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'TreeNodeNormal'.ts(2345)
type TreeNodeValue = string | number | string[] | number[];

type TreeNodeNormal = {
  value: TreeNodeValue;
  children?: TreeNodeNormal[];
}

export function getAllChildrenNodes<T = TreeNodeNormal>(
  node: TreeNodeNormal | undefined | null,
  mapper?: (node: TreeNodeNormal) => T,
  children: T[] = []
): T[] {
  if (!node || !Array.isArray(node.children)) return children;

  for (const child of node.children) {
    if (typeof mapper === "function") {
      children.push(mapper(child));
    } else {
      children.push(child);  // TSC throws error here
    }
    children = children.concat(getAllChildrenNodes(child, mapper));
  }

  return children;
}

Got error:
Argument of type 'TreeNodeNormal' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'TreeNodeNormal'.ts(2345)

The only choice is to use type assertion like this?
children.push(child as unknown as T);

TS Playground
UPDATE:
Sample data:
const treeData = [
  {
    title: 'Node1',
    value: '0-0',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Child Node1',
        value: '0-0-1',
      },
      {
        title: 'Child Node2',
        value: '0-0-2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Node2',
    value: '0-1',
  },
]

Get value of all nodes:
getAllChildrenNodes({children: treeData}, (node) => node.value)
// ['0-0', '0-0-1', '0-0-2', '0-1']

So, the T[] is string[]

"The only choice is to use type assertion like this?" That will make your function not typesafe, putting a TreeNodeNormal into an array that may expect a subtype of it. See the answers to previous questions about this.

Consider the call getAllChildrenNodes<number>(/* args */) - then T = number and not TreeNodeNormal. It's the caller who decides what the generic type argument is in the end

Does this code even need to be generic? The only possible value for T is TreeNodeNormal. I don't think you can use any other type there, since T determines the type of the children to use (only TreeNodeNormal) and what the mapper produces (also only bound by the type of the children).  using (node) => node.value as the mapper implies T can also be TreeNodeValue but if that's the case else { children.push(child); } doesn't fit because you cannot add a child (TreeNodeNormal) into an array of TreeNodeValue

@VLAZ If generic is not necessary, can you post an answer?

Before your update it looked like the only valid options for T were TreeNodeNormal thus the generic was superfluous. However, after the update it turns out you do want to key off T on what mapper returns. Which wasn't evident from your initial question. And the code couldn't really work in generic bounds anyway as I pointed out before because (as TS rightly warns you) the else part cannot work for any T which isn't TreeNodeNormal. The solution here isn't less to try and trick the compiler but properly express the operation you want to do.

The problem here is that you can't force default function arguments to correspond to default generic type arguments. It's a missing feature as per ms/TS#56315. The easiest thing is to use a type assertion (see that issue).  Here I'd probably write your code as shown in this playground link but note that the actual work I did was in fixing your generics, not the type assertion. Could you [edit] the code in the question to make the generics make sense (so it's a [mre]), and then answers could focus on the defaults issue?

I think you need 2 versions of the getAllChildrenNodes() function:
One with a mapper (with a generic type as mapper output):
export function getAllChildrenNodes<T = TreeNodeNormal>(
    node: TreeNodeNormal | undefined | null,
    mapper: (node: TreeNodeNormal) => T,
    children: T[] = []
): T[] {
    if (!node || !Array.isArray(node.children)) return children;

    for (const child of node.children) {
        children.push(mapper(child));
        children = children.concat(getAllChildrenNodes(child, mapper));
    }

    return children;
}

one without mapper - this one does not need to be generic then:
export function getAllChildrenNodesNoMapper(
    node: TreeNodeNormal | undefined | null,
    children: TreeNodeNormal[] = []
): TreeNodeNormal[] {
    if (!node || !Array.isArray(node.children)) return children;

    for (const child of node.children) {
        children.push(child);
        children = children.concat(getAllChildrenNodesNoMapper(child));
    }

    return children;
}

